# Kafka MirrorMaker 2 re-creating the deleted source topic in source for active-passive mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have a MM2 service running between 2 Kafka clusters in the Active-Passive mode. Upon deleting a topic from the source, MM2 is re-creating the topic again in the source node. Is is the expected behaviour for Active-Passive model?

I believe it to be the case when we delete the topic from the target cluster, but I am finding this in the source cluster.

I tried deleting the one of the source topic from the source cluster while the MirrorMaker 2 service was running. i was expecting the topic to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

By default `auto.create.topics.enable` is set to `true`. If you do not disable this setting, it's possible MirrorMaker will recreate topics on the source cluster when they are deleted.

The reason is that MirrorMaker only checks topics on each cluster at a regular interval. But it continuously tries to consume records, so if a topic is deleted, it's very likely the source cluster will receive a consumer request and recreate the topic automatically instead of MirrorMaker detecting the topic has been deleted and stop its consumers.